# Script to login and load main gui in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: bash, login, auto-login

I have a RFID reader interfaced with an Arduino microcontroller left over from a past project, which I would now like to use to automatically login on Ubuntu 11.10. What I'm imagining specifically is that I would start up my computer normally, it would get to the login screen for Ubuntu, I would swipe my RFID card and Ubuntu would then begin loading the desktop and everything as though I had typed in my password.

I have a python script already made that can read the RFID tag and use it to decrypt my password, and I can set it up to run when the computer starts up. I just have no idea what scripts Ubuntu runs when a user logs in.

Basically, all I need to know is what to add to my script so Ubuntu will load my profile and desktop as though I had just entered my password on the normal login screen.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have to come up with something that hooks into PAM (Pluggable Authentication Module). For obvious reasons, authentication mechanisms are quite tricky to deal with. I suggest reading up on all things related to PAM and then hooking in to your welcome screen, which is likely `lightdm` unless you've changed it.

Aside from that your project is really cool (which it is!), I would cautiously recommend against securing your system solely with a physical object that someone can steal or borrow, since it would give them access to everything on your computer should they obtain it.

Comment: Awesome, I will get to reading up on PAM and lightdm. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I really just had no idea where to start. And you are absolutely right about the security issue. I have most of my important files encrypted and I wouldn't plan on bringing the rfid reader outside of my house, so I'm not overly concerned about it though. I'm mostly interested in doing this for learning more about linux/the coolness factor rather than practical reasons, haha.